# Tabitems in a functions

Tags: shiny

I am trying to capture tabitems under a function(there is a specific reason for this). But not able to achieve as per below code.

Why am I not able to return as list. The tab items  i have called inside a function called c_b. But not able to render it

Method 1 : (Direct Method)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)


c_b <- div(tabItem(
      tabName = "menu1",dataTableOutput("tab")
    ),
    tabItem(
      tabName = "menu2",dataTableOutput("tab1")))
  

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("menu1", tabName = "menu1", icon = icon("table")),
      menuItem("menu2", tabName = "menu2", icon = icon("table"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "menu1",dataTableOutput("tab")
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "menu2",dataTableOutput("tab1"))
    )
  )
  
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
output$tab <- renderDataTable({
  datatable(iris)
})
  
output$tab1 <- renderDataTable({
  datatable(iris)
})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Method 2 :
Here instead of writing inside tabitems, I am creating a div. But not working

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)


c_b <- div(tabItem(
      tabName = "menu1",dataTableOutput("tab")
    ),
    tabItem(
      tabName = "menu2",dataTableOutput("tab1")))
  

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("menu1", tabName = "menu1", icon = icon("table")),
      menuItem("menu2", tabName = "menu2", icon = icon("table"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      c_b
    )
  )
  
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
output$tab <- renderDataTable({
  datatable(iris)
})
  
output$tab1 <- renderDataTable({
  datatable(iris)
})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `do.call` on `tabItems` as shown below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

c_b <- list(
  tabItem(
    tabName = "menu1",DTOutput("tab1")
  ),
  tabItem(
    tabName = "menu2",DTOutput("tab2")
  )
  )

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("menu1", tabName = "menu1", icon = icon("table")),
      menuItem("menu2", tabName = "menu2", icon = icon("table"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    do.call(tabItems, c_b)
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$tab1 <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris)
  })
  
  output$tab2 <- renderDT({
    datatable(cars)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```